# Looping through an array for strings and putting the found strings into another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, strstr

Im trying to loop through the $files array and:

1. Find occurrences of "some-string".
2. For every "some-string" occurrence found, i need to add it to an array. (ie. $some_strings).
3. Finally be able to call $some_string array outside of the for loop for manipulation(ie. count(), $some_string[1])

   ```
   foreach($files as $key=>$value)
   {
   if(strstr($value,'some-string')){
       $some_strings = array();
       $some_strings = $files[$key];
       unset($files[$key]);
   } elseif (strstr($value,'php')) {
       unset($files[$key]);
     }


   }
   ```

Every things seems to work fine until i try count($some_strings). This only returns 1 value when i know there are atleast 10 values. WHat am i doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to move the line initialising `$some_strings` to outside the loop.

Comment: Ok. I'll move this outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$some_strings = array();
foreach($files as $key=>$value)
{
    if(strstr($value,'some-string')){
       $some_strings[] = $files[$key];
       unset($files[$key]);
    } elseif (strstr($value, 'php')) {
      unset($files[$key]);
    }
}
//Now you can use $some_strings here without a problem
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 foreach($files as $key=>$value)
 {
   if(strstr($value,'some-string'))
   {
     $some_strings[$key] = $value;
      unset($files[$key]);
   } elseif (strstr($value,'php')) 
   {
     $another_strings[$key] = $value;
      unset($files[$key]);
   }
 }

 echo count( $some_strings);
 echo count( $another_strings);
```